# Android - RelativeLayout Problems

Tags: android, android-layout

In a relativelayout images are cascaded on top of another based on your xml file. How do you indicate what image should be at the very top?

Is there a way to do this in code instead of xml?

I am attaching my XML file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:src="@drawable/payarrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    android:src="@drawable/chargearrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/landingDockLeft"
    android:src="@drawable/landingdock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/landingDockRight"
    android:src="@drawable/landingdock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Comment: the last view inside the `RelativeLayout` will be the top-most view

Answer (score 1):

In xml, you can use `layout_alignParentTop="true"` to put the view on the very top.  Then make liberal use of `layout_below="@+id/id_of_view_to_be_below"` to ensure that the view is always below the top view.

In code, you have to use [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int,%20int%29) with the related attributes and apply them to the child views.

Example in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:src="@drawable/payarrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    android:src="@drawable/chargearrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img1"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/landingDockLeft"
    android:src="@drawable/landingdock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img2"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/landingDockRight"
    android:src="@drawable/landingdock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/landingDockLeft"
    />
```

This will put them all stacked on top of each other with the `img1` view at the very top of the entire thing.

The coding way is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191099/how-to-set-relativelayout-layout-params-in-code-not-in-xml).

Comment: Hey Deev, thank you but this is not what I wanted. I want the images to be cascaded on top of one another. One layer on top of the other layer. I want them to overlap. However, I want img1 to be directly on top of img3 and img4 on no matter what. Do you know how this can be done? Layout_alignParentTop and stuff only takes care of making sure that the image view exists in a row by itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: The z-order of the views should remain the same throughout the life of the app unless you specify otherwise.  You can use attributes such as `layout_alignTop`, `layout_alignBottom`, `layout_alignLeft`, and `layout_alignBottom` to align views to other views based on their locations.  I haven't tried this, but I bet if you put `android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img1"` and `android:layout_alignLeft="@id/img1"` to `img2`, it would align img2 to the top left corner of img1.

Answer (score 0):

android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

Answer (score 0):

This is the example:
1) if you put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    />    
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img2"
    />
```

ImageView with id img1 will be under ImageView with id img2.

---

2) and if you want to put TextView which will be under ImageView with id img2 you do like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        />        
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        />
```

so it is matter of ordering.