# android:layout_alignParentBottom by code

Tags: android, alignment

How to set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for a videoview, by code and not from xml?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I assume you are trying to add your `VideoView` to a `RelativeLayout` ?

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.your_relative_layout);
mVideo = new VideoView(this); 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); // or wrap_content
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
relativeLayout.addView(mVideo , layoutParams);
```

Comment: I don't think there is a `ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM` for `LinearLayout`, you have to use `android:gravity="bottom"` or [setGravity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setGravity%28int%29) to bottom.

Comment: I changed LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and it works ..thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
YourVideoView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 2):

get layout params from your view and add rule

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
 lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some References are [Here1](http://prativas.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/modify-the-views-of-relativelayout-in-xml-through-code/) and [Here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191099/how-to-set-relativelayout-layout-params-in-code-not-in-xml)

this is what you have to do:

Create a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams object.
Use addRule(int) or addRule(int, int) to set the rules. The first method is used to add rules that don’t require values.
Set the parameters to the view (in this case, to each button).

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,RelativeLayout.TRUE);  
    yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.