# android MoPub ad align

Tags: android

hello how to show mopub ad at the bottom?

I have this code

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        mopView = new MoPubView(this);
            mopView.setAdUnitId(PUB_ID_320x50);
            mopView.setLayoutParams(params);
            mopView.loadAd();
            mainRelative.addView(mopView, params);
```

but it show in center of screen , how to align to bottom? 
p.s. my main layout is RelativeLayout

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5191099/1012284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//change your layout height to ill parent

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

Comment: Ru adding thid relative any other parent layout?