# error overriding OnMeasure method

Tags: android, android-layout, fullscreen, android-videoview

hi I'm working in my android app which plays videos and now I want to control my video to play in full screen I have a code but it contains errors it says that void is not valid type for variable onmeasure I dont know how to correct that

```
public class video extends Activity {


String SrcPath =  "rtsp://v8.cache3.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQltaP8vg4qMsBMYDSANFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYOL6qv2DoMPrUAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.video1);


protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
   int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
   int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
   this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth/2, parentHeight);
   this.setLayoutParams(new *ParentLayoutType*.LayoutParams(parentWidth/2,parentHeight));
   super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}


VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vview);
myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
myVideoView.requestFocus();

}
 }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The compilation problem is that there are bracket issues. Move

```
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
   int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
   int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
   this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth/2, parentHeight);
   this.setLayoutParams(new *ParentLayoutType*.LayoutParams(parentWidth/2,parentHeight));
   super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

So it is *not* in `onCreate()`. Right now, methods can't directly enclose other methods.

Also, [`onMeasure()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29) is not a method in `Activity`, but instead in `View`. You should review the documentation so you figure out exactly what you want to do.

Comment: ok I have taken it off the oncreate and placed it after that oncreate  but still getting error for new at this.setlayoutparams....I guess I should replace it with my layout.....and that's what I did but it can't be resolved as variable,

Comment: @user1794499 Keep in mind that `onMeasure()` is a View method. You're working in an `Activity`. As for the setting of the layout params, since this method was for a View class, it uses `this`. What you want instead is to reference your view, which I think you want is your VideoView. Just make the reference an instance variable, that's all.

Comment: okay got it but what type my variable should be, int? sorry for bothering buddy

Comment: @user1794499 If you're trying to reference a `VideoView`, your type would be `VideoView`. What variable are you talking about?

Comment: I mean if I'll do as you said...using an instance variable to refference my layout let's say we call that variable new as it's already there in .setlayoutparams....I guess I should give it layout as it's type not videoview coz I need to reference the layout not only the within view

Comment: @user1794499 The `new` keyword is reserved, it can't be a variable. Secondly, you should be working with the View you want to modify. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191099/how-to-set-relativelayout-layout-params-in-code-not-in-xml) question about how to use `setLayoutParams()`. And just a tip: learn Java first before Android.

Comment: anyway I found someway to do it "at least partially what I need" by including videoview in a relativelayout and set all alignments attributes of that view to true and give fill parent for width and height       thanks alot guys and thanks @A--C for the tip

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might want to have these two functions as methods in your class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video1);

    // Set up the video when you create the activity
    VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vview);
    myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
    myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    myVideoView.requestFocus();
}

// On measure should be a different method also in the class video
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
   int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
   int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
   this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth/2, parentHeight);
   this.setLayoutParams(new *ParentLayoutType*.LayoutParams(parentWidth/2,parentHeight));
   super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Comment: can u just confirm me with new parameter at .setlayoutparams.. should it be my xml file name?

Comment: I'm not sure but you could find out by looking in the xml. The top level view in video1.xml will most likely be called a ____Layout. For example: it might be LinearLayout in which case I think it would make the parameter `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(parentWidth/2,parentHeight)`