# how to avoid overlapping of dynamically positioned views

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

how to avoid overlapping of dynamically positioned views?

I have a RelativeLayout , and i am adding views dynamically(at runtime) at particular position(x,y coordinates) but the problem is the views are overlapping.
How to avoid this.

Thanks in advance.[image]

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_main"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </RelativeLayout>
         <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ll_mainBottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>
```

javacode

```
 ll_main = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_main);

            if (views[3].equals("textView")) {


                TextView tv_new = new TextView(TenMinActivity.this);
                // location
                int x = Integer.parseInt(views[12]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(views[13]);

                String bgColor = "#" + views[4];
                String fgColor = "#" + Views[5];

            tv_new.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(bgColor)); // Bg Color
        tv_new.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(fgColor)); // Text color


                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            width, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.leftMargin = x;
    params.topMargin = y;

                ll_main.addView(tv_new, params);
}else if(views[3].equals("edittext")){

    ....

}
```

Comment: what about changing relative layout to linear

Comment: @RenjithKN  Sir  , if i am using LinearLayout im unable to set view at particular positions.It is displaying all views vertically. ex.Name(Textview)<br/>(EditText)<br/>Age(Tv)<br/>

Answer (score 1):

Give

```
android:paddingLeft=""
```

and  to each element so that the ones to the left most of the screen will have bit of space. and the ones to the right,give

```
android:paddingBottom=""
```

First,check the first 2 elements that is the name text and your text field after that you can proceed to the rest.

I can guide you better,if you post your code

Check this,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingl="10dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @latif mohammad khan,do you have any sort of compulsion to code in java directly..why can't you code in the layouts?

Comment: Sir ,actually we get all this views(view BG color,View Textsize,textcolor,....... ,x-coordinate y-coordinate position ) dynamically. I(in code) have to check weather this is EditText,Radio,..etc and add to layout at given position. @user

Comment: @latif mohammad khan, Ok then,I would suggest you to implement it as we do it for the list view...create a layout and fix the positions and then check the conditions and then add the values dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how layouts work, first try to make the same layout in xml. Then you will learn that this kind of layout can easily be made using `LinearLayout`.

You can use parent `LinearLayout` and add sublayouts to it. Now you say if you use `LinearLayout` all subviews are shown vertically. It shows vertically because you are adding them one by one. If you take a `RelativeLayout` and add your `TextView` and `EditText` to it and then add that `RelativeLayout` to your `LinearLayout`, you will get the desired result.

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <TextView />
        <EditText />//use layout_margin or layout_toLeftOf for moving to to right
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout>
        <TextView/>
        <EditText/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sir ,actually we get all this views(view BG color,View Textsize,textcolor,....... ,x-coordinate y-coordinate position ) dynamically. I(in code) have to check weather this is EditText,Radio,..etc and add to layout at given position,I should write through code only @naveen

Answer (score 0):

Please use Layout params like layout_below layout_above toRightof and ToLeftof  when you add a  view to container relative layout

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5191159/1911784

Comment: Sir,I cant use this because I have to insert at particular position  in the layout(at runtime) ie(x,y coordinates given).

Comment: @latifmohammadkhan In Android there are many devices with different width and height so please don't use x ,y coordinate, it will make many alignment issues in different devices. so try to use layout params thats better

Comment: Yes, in some devices the view is good. could you please send code (as u said :use layout params thats better) @user1911784 I have used     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(    
                width,     android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.leftMargin = x;
        params.topMargin = y;   plz see my code given.

Answer (score 0):

you an use below code to add views in your layout

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            TextView text2 = new TextView(context);         
                        newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                        newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                   newParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, text1.getId());
            text2.setLayoutParams(newParams);
            layout.addView(text2);
```

where layout is your main layout.

you can use other params as well - like rightof, leftof etc

Comment: Sir,I cant use this because I have to insert at particular position in the layout(at runtime) ie(x,y coordinates given). Please see the code given.