# Android : Set padding of image in ImageButton programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

I have a problem with an ImageButton. The position of my image is not good into the ImageButton.

is there a way to fix that programmatically ?

[image]

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/nouvelle_annonce_choose_image"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textColor="@color/blanc" />
```

**rounded_button.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/blanc"/>
    <stroke android:width="3sp" android:color="@color/blue_dark_normal" />
</shape>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191099/how-to-set-relativelayout-layout-params-in-code-not-in-xml :- Go Through this link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've started to do it, with the `android:layout_marginTop`. Either add a bottom margin, or else just us `layout_margin`, and you should be able to adjust the image as desired.

In fact, it's because of the `android:layout_marginTop` that your image is off centered. It is putting a large margin at the top of the image, without compensating for it at the bottom.

If margin doesn't work, then try playing with padding. Padding affects how things are aligned within the image. Padding is simply `android:padding`, or `android:paddingBottom` attributes.

Comment: I use `android:layout_marginTop` to set the position of the ImageButton from other view. Not to set the position of my image inside my Imagebutton

Comment: Added more about padding, which should center the image better within the image.

Comment: Ok with padding it's OK

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your ImageButton xml:

```
android:scaleType="center"
```

Comment: Same result. I think that is my image which is not well formated

Comment: Probably the image has empty space at top.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in ImageButton xml

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```