# Can I set the position of the widget with programming in android

Tags: android

Can I set the position of the widget  with programming in android instead the `xml` code. For example:

[image]

And like these. Are there methods instead the above `xml` code to use?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191099/how-to-set-relativelayout-layout-params-in-code-not-in-xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can set all the circled attributes via code aswell. For example this code aligns the **button1** to the left of its parent (RelativeLayout) and positions **button2** left of **button1**.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
button1.setLayoutParams(params);

params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, button1.getId());
button2.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Keep in mind that

- layout_alignTop
- layout_alignEnd
- layout_alignParentBottom
- layout_alignParentLeft
- layout_alignParentStart
- layout_toRightOf
- layout_above
- layout_below
- layout_centerInParent
- layout_centerHorizontal

will work only if the view you are setting the attributes to, is inside a **RelativeLayout**.

Original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191099/how-to-set-relativelayout-layout-params-in-code-not-in-xml),

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, for example

```
Button button1 = new Button(R.id.buttonn);
Button button2 = new Button(R.id.buttonn2);
button1.setX(button2.getX);
```

There are more functions like `setX` , if you need something spesificly just ask for it :)