# dynamically changing buttons positions in android based on server response

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

From server I get a list of payment types like CreditCardPayment, PayPalCheckout, GoogleWallet. Based on what order these are sent in a list from the server my ordering of buttons on the screen will change. Could someone give pointers on how change the buttons positions dynamically on the screen ?

Comment: do you want to set X and Y for it ?

Comment: nope It will be like                                                                                   button w button x                                                                                                         button y button  z

Comment: Why don't you set `button` text dynamically in place of changing buttons positions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative layout for that. and use attrbutes like `RelativeLayout.BELOW` in your code for dynamically changing position as per requirement. 
Please check [How to set RelativeLayout layout params in code not in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191099/how-to-set-relativelayout-layout-params-in-code-not-in-xml) link

You need to create layout dynamically as below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Boolean button1ontop;
    Boolean button2ontop;
    Boolean button3ontop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        button1ontop=false;
        button2ontop=true;
        button3ontop=false;
        //create new layout and set height and width
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        //add buttons
        Button b1 = new Button(this);
        Button b2 = new Button(this);
        Button b3 = new Button(this);
        b1.setText("Button1");
        b1.setId(R.id.button1);
        b2.setId(R.id.button2);
        b3.setId(R.id.button3);
        b2.setText("Button2");
        b3.setText("Button3");
       // Toast.makeText(this,(b1.getId()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        if(button1ontop){
            b1.setLayoutParams(lp);
            lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.button1);
            b2.setLayoutParams(lp1);
            lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.button2);
            b3.setLayoutParams(lp2);
        }
        else if(button2ontop){
            b2.setLayoutParams(lp);
            lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.button2);
            b1.setLayoutParams(lp1);
            lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.button1);
            b3.setLayoutParams(lp2);
        }
        else if(button3ontop){
            b3.setLayoutParams(lp);
            lp1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.button3);
            b1.setLayoutParams(lp1);
            lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.button1);
            b2.setLayoutParams(lp2);
        }
        relativeLayout.addView(b1);
        relativeLayout.addView(b2);
        relativeLayout.addView(b3);

        setContentView(relativeLayout, layoutParams);

    }



}
```

Crete file ids.xml in res/values folder and define ids

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="id" name="button1" />
    <item type="id" name="button2" />
    <item type="id" name="button3" />

</resources>
```

Modify this code as per your requirement

Comment: in my layout i have 3 buttons layout added. Order of dispalying these i want to change dynamically in code

Comment: I have a frame layout for google wallet in my layout. I cannot declare that dynamically in my code. I can only get a reference to that in code and then change its positions dynamically but not sure how do i do that here