# How to set LinearLayout LayoutParams to show all height

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, layoutparams

Based in this question [How to set RelativeLayout layout params in code not in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191099/how-to-set-relativelayout-layout-params-in-code-not-in-xml) I've made this code:

```
    LinearLayout oLl = new LinearLayout(getContext());

    TextView oNum = new TextView(getContext());
    oNum.setText(String.valueOf(nPos + 1) + ". ");
    oNum.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    oNum.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    oNum.setTextSize(18);
    oNum.setPadding(Dp_to_Px(10),Dp_to_Px(15),0,0);

    TextView oText = new TextView(getContext());
    oText.setText(oPreg.getcPregunta());
    oText.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    oText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    oText.setTextSize(18);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams oLp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    oLl.addView(oNum);
    oLl.addView(oText,oLp);

    oContainer.addView(oLl,oLp);
```

But It cuts the last line.

[image]

EDIT:

The code of the Radio Buttons:

```
 RadioGroup oRg = new RadioGroup(getContext());
    oRg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
    oRg.setPadding(Dp_to_Px(10),Dp_to_Px(6),0,0);

    RadioButton oRbSi = new RadioButton(getContext());
    oRbSi.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.Si));
    oRbSi.setPadding(0,0,Dp_to_Px(25),Dp_to_Px(5));

    RadioButton oRbNo = new RadioButton(getContext());
    oRbNo.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.No));

    oRg.addView(oRbSi);
    oRg.addView(oRbNo);

    oContainer.addView(oRg);
```

And the oContainer definition:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/encuesta_frg_contaier"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong but can't we set wrap content height to linear layout in xml?

Comment: @Nobody Yes, but I need to create my controls dynamically at this point of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of this: `oNum.setPadding(Dp_to_Px(10),Dp_to_Px(15),0,0);`

The `oNum` TextView has padding on the top, which is pushing the `oText` TextView below the `oRg` RadioGroup. Try setting the padding on `oLl` instead, and your issue should be solved.